# I can't search on Twitter API v2 with various options

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

I want to get tweets by [recent search](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/paginate) with various option.

The following URL gives an error. This is the case when searching for 'snow'.

```html
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=snow&next_token=*****&tweet.fields=author_id -is:retweet lang:ja
```

This is error.

```html
(400, '{"errors":[{"parameters":{"next_token":["***** -is:retweet lang:ja"]},"message":"The `next_token` query parameter value [***** -is:retweet lang:ja] is not a valid token."}],"title":"Invalid Request","detail":"One or more parameters to your request was invalid.","type":"https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/invalid-request"}')
```

In the URL, if I delete one of 'next_token' and '-is:retweet lang:ja', it works fine. The error only occurs when both are specified.
Is there a difference in the way they are specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query operators need to be part of the `query` parameter. In your example you've tagged them onto the end.

So your total `query` would be
"snow -is:retweet lang:ja"

You might also find it helpful to make `next_token` the final parameter, since you pick it up and append it from the result of the last query - that way it will not get mixed up with anything else.

`https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=snow -is:retweet lang:ja&tweet.fields=author_id&next_token=*****`

Comment: I see... Thanks to you, I understand now. Also, your sample code is very helpful to me. Thank you very much <(_ _)>.

Comment: Feel free to mark my answer as a solution to the problem, this will help others. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much. This answer helped me as well!